# Lodash: Find and delete an item in a multi-level Json based on a conditions

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash

I am trying to delete an item in an "roles array" based on a condition, but this array is an item in a json array. Also I have to check one more condition at the parent level before looking in to the roles array. I tired lodash's find to first match the first condition at the parent level, but couldn't able to proceed further with the next level of filtering.

My json:

```
[ {"unitId": "2", name: "elizabeth", roles: [{ "role":{"roleId" : "2", roleName: "testing"}},  { "role":{"roleId" : "5", roleName: "dev"}}]},
{"unitId": "2", name: "peter", roles: [{ "role":{"roleId" : "1", roleName: "testing"}},  { "role":{"roleId" : "2", roleName: "dev"}}]}
]
```

Expected result:

```
[ {"unitId": "2", name: "elizabeth", roles: [{ "role":{"roleId" : "2", roleName: "testing"}}}]},
{"unitId": "2", name: "peter", roles: [{ "role":{"roleId" : "1", roleName: "testing"}},  { "role":{"roleId" : "2", roleName: "dev"}}]}
]
```

Here I need to first check for unitId : 2, and then delete any roles with roleId: 5 in that unitId: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` & `remove` with lodash:

```js
const data = [{ unitId: "2", name: "elizabeth", roles: [{ "role": { "roleId": "2", roleName: "testing" } }, { "role": { "roleId": "5", roleName: "dev" } }] }, { unitId: "2", name: "peter", roles: [{ "role": { "roleId": "1", roleName: "testing" } }, { "role": { "roleId": "2", roleName: "dev" } }] } ]

const result = _.map(data, x => (_.isEqual(x.unitId, "2") ? 
   _.remove(x.roles, y => y.role.roleId == "5") : null, x))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You could also skip lodash and do:

```js
const data = [{ unitId: "2", name: "elizabeth", roles: [{ "role": { "roleId": "2", roleName: "testing" } }, { "role": { "roleId": "5", roleName: "dev" } }] }, { unitId: "2", name: "peter", roles: [{ "role": { "roleId": "1", roleName: "testing" } }, { "role": { "roleId": "2", roleName: "dev" } }] } ]

const result = data.map(x => (x.roles = x.unitId == "2" ? 
  x.roles.filter(y => y.role.roleId != '5') : x.roles, x))

console.log(result)
```

With using `map` and `filter`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please find my edits to the question. Actually, roleId and roleName are part of role. Sorry for missing it

Comment: Updated the anwer

Comment: It worked great. Thanks @Akrion. I have one more use case where I need to add a new role to the roles array. I tried push of lodash, but it didn't work.

Comment: Post it as another question with the code you have tried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937484/lodash-find-and-add-an-item-in-a-multi-level-json-based-on-a-conditions